# Finding the kernel and image of a reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be the reflection about the plane 
$$L = \operatorname{span} \{ (1,2,-1),(0,2,1)\}.$$

1) Find the kernel and image of $T$.

2) Verify that the $ \dim \ker T + \dim \operatorname{Image}T = 3$.

Question: Is there fast/intuitive way of solving this problems with the given information? My approach was rather lengthy and most likely unnecessary.

My work: I found an orthogonal vector to the basis $(-4,1,-2)$, then found the scalars of the three vectors, then computed the transformation, providing me with the analytical expression and then after many lengthy computations got my answer.

Edit: Thank you for the answers. I got the idea.

Comment: Hint: What effect does a reflection have on the reflecting plane?

Answer (score 4):

Since $T$ is a reflection, we have $T^2 = I$. Thus $T$ is bijective. This implies

$$\ker T = \{ (0,0,0)\},  \ \ \ \operatorname{Image} T = \mathbb R^3$$

and this implies the equality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=(1,2,-1)$, and let $v=(0,2,1)$. Then $u$, $v$ are linearly independent eigenvectors, with eigenvalue $1$. Let $w=u\times v$, i.e. the cross-product of $u$ of $v$. Then $w$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$.

Since $u$, $v$, $w$ are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and they are all in the Image of $T$, we have that the Image of $T$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Since $u$, $v$, $w$ are a basis of eigenvectors, with eigenvalues $1$, $1$, $-1$ respectively, the matrix with respect to this basis is a diagonal matrix with $1$, $1$, and $-1$ on the diagonal. So the determinant of $T$ is $-1$. Since $T$ has non-zero determinant, the kernel of $T$ is trivial.

It follows that the image has dimension $3$ and the kernel has dimension $0$.

Comment: Trivial indeed my friend. Thank you.